# 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the ArangoDB response is 'false'

Tags: vue.js, arangodb, arangojs

I am trying to get the documents from an ArangoDb database collection , from a Vuejs application. When I run the code below in a node console, it works fine.

```
  Database = require('arangojs').Database;
  aqlQuery = require('arangojs').aqlQuery;
  const db = new Database();
  db.useBasicAuth('root', 'degfra');
  db.useDatabase('mydb');
  let collection = db.collection('firstCollection');

  db.query(aqlQuery`
    FOR doc IN ${collection}
    SORT doc.value ASC
    RETURN doc._key
    `).then(
      cursor => cursor.all()
    ).then(
      keys => console.log('All keys:', keys.join(', ')),
      err => console.error('Failed to execute query:', err)
    );
  }
```

But when I run it from the Vuejs application (the only difference is that I replace the 'require' statements with " import {Database, aql} from 'arangojs' " ), it returns :

Failed to load http://localhost:8529/_db/mydb/_api/cursor: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is 'false' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Could it be that the ' db.useBasicAuth('root', 'degfra'); ' does not work in the application? Or is there another concern about using arangojs in the Browser?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1882

Comment: Also, make sure you set your trusted origin, as described here: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/HTTP/General/#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-requests